# Why am I asked to declare a fucntion from a different file when I have included the header file of that file at the beginning?

Tags: c++, header-files

I thought the entire point of a header file is to avoid repetitive forward declaration? I wrote three c++ files respectively named: fact.c++, fact.h++ (header file), and main.c++. Here are the codes:

This is fact.c++, storing a function that calculates the factorial of an integer:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorial(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int fact=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
     fact=fact*i;
     
    }
    return fact;
}
```

This is fact.h++, a header file for our fact.c++:

```
//the header file for the factorial fucntion from fact.c++ file

#ifndef FACT_H
#define FACT_H

int factorial();


#endif
```

and finally main.cpp, where the main method is:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "fact.h++"
using namespace std;

int main(){

cout<<"The factorial value of your number is "<<factorial()<<endl;

}
```

As you can see from above that I have included the fact.h++ header file, expecting not having to declare the factorial function before using it. But when I ran the codes I was told "factorial" was not declared at this scope. I was using Microsoft visual studio code with the coderunner plugin. Why is this happening? Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Do you have two files, "fact.h++" and "fact.hpp"?

Comment: 1. "fact.hpp" and "fact.h++" are two different files. 2. Your "fact.cpp" does not include "fact.hpp"

Comment: @UnholySheep In my editor everything is .h++ and c++. I'm just calling them hpp/cpp in my question body. Sorry for the confusion (

Comment: The `fact` function should take a parameter and not read it from the user (your function is impossible to reuse). You should also include `<iostream>`, but not `<stdio.h>`, in "main.cpp". (Are you sure that the compiler isn't complaining about `cout` and `endl`?)

Comment: i tried to fix it, not sure if I missed one. Please dont change things to make it "simpler" for us like that. Calling files by a different name only adds confusion

Comment: please include the compiler error message in the quesiton

Comment: I suspect the real problem is that you included `<stdio.h>` which, even if correctly spelled `<cstdio>`, should _actually_ be `<iostream>` ... and your real problem is that the compiler doesn't recognise `cout`. That's why it is important to **paste** the entire, exact error message, and not paraphrase it.

Comment: @UnholySheep while it's a good practice to always include a header in its corresponding source file, it's not actually required. This is one of the case where it should work.

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64372912/edit) your question. Code / compiler output in comments is not readable

Comment: @idclev 463035818 Here is my error message:
PS C:\Users\user\hello> cd "c:\Users\user\hello\multi_include.c++\" ; if ($?) { g++ main.c++ -o main } ; if ($?) { .\main }    
main.c++: In function 'int main()':
main.c++:9:49: error: 'factorial' was not declared in this scope
    9 | cout<<"The factorial value of your number is "<<factorial()<<endl;
      |                                                 ^~~~~~~~~
PS C:\Users\user\hello\multi_include.c++>

Comment: @THE_ILLUMINATITHUGGA my last comment